# What pattern should I set for handling event as working item?

Tags: event-programming, message-queue

I have this business event : "CustomerUpdated" published by my system.

I have many application listening to these events, and they do all king of action : sending email, updating the database, erasing cache etc ... so I can't use a queue here, but I can't use a topic, because If 2 instance of the mailing application are running (I created them for scalability), the email will be send twice : once by each instance.

So what should I do :

- have a unique instance that is listening to the event and then publish a work item to the queue "SendCustomerUpdatedEmail" ? : but that would add a bottleneck to my app (not a big one though)
- save a "CustomerUpdatedEmailsHandled" on a centralized place (db), and save here something that identifies the event (guid)
- An other really smart pattern that I couldn't figure out

PS : I posted this on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38569688/how-to-make-sur-my-event-is-handled-by-only-one-instance-of-my-app?noredirect=1#comment64777122_38569688 but I didn't get any answer (only someone telling me I made bad decisions but without solutions) and it seems that stackoverflow was made for "coding" questions so ...

Comment: Can you not simply use topic-based producer/consumer queue. So the event is put on the email queue, DB-update queue etc by the producer system. Consumer systems responsible for those individual queues then pop off the first event and handle it. That way you can have multiple email handlers and only one DB-update handler, for example.

Comment: @DavidArno indeed this would work, but that would add coupling between the producer and the consumer : I would have to change the producer code every time I have a new consumer, this seems like a bad thing. If I do this I can just do a classical method call.

Comment: Are all `CustomerUpdated` events sent to all consumers? If so, then the producer part need only be given a set of queues to populate; it need know nothing about what consumes those queues. So there should be no need for coupling.

Comment: I can indeed add a method to the producer "add queue" and then a configuration file / data store would reference these

Comment: Topic seems appropriate to me.  I think the problem with your email server situation is an email server problem.  You shouldn't tell two email servers to send the same message.  If you want HA email sending, that is its own problem with its own set of solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You have, actually, described exactly what you should do in your first suggested solution: if you have multiple apps listening to the same event, then you definitely have to use topic based approach. That said, scalability should not be resolved only on the source side, but on the recipient side too. This means that each application should have its own queue, and get events from there.

Considering that this queue is just a flow-through structure, it should not be much of a bottleneck. If it proves to be so, you can always add more processing power and maybe design some sort of round robin data publishing (this is the part where scalability is implemented on a source side). The idea here would be that you would have n `SendCustomerUpdatedEmail` queues and an event from the topic would be published to one of those queues, associated to one instance of the `SendCustomerUpdatedEmail` application. That way, the message would be sent to one instance of the queue only and processed only once, while other instances would remain available for other events at the same time.

Comment: This answer gave me the following idea. We use redis as our message broker, so I have a component that do the linking between a channel and a redis list (the working item queue), when the event occurs it pushed the message on the X queues (email, db ...). The consumers listen to the keyspace notifications on those list and do a lpop, so only one of them pick the message. What do you think ?

Comment: First of all, let me say that personally, I have never worked with redis. Having said that, conceptually, it sounds fine to me. If I understood correctly, you will distribute the event on X queues, one for each type application, where multiple instances of each type of application can be associated to the same queue. Then, one of the application instances will pick up the message from the queue, and that way you will ensure that the event is processed only once. This means that the speed of processing will basically be a function of queue throughput.

Comment: that's what I meant, I'll try to find if someone already did this kind of thing, thanks (i'll wait a bit before validating your answer maybe there is something better)

Comment: If you find something interesting, do let us know. I am very curious to see how you end up implementing this solution.